# Why did Magneto betray Apocalypse?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-apocalypse

Magneto, speaking with Apocalypse says

> **Apocalypse:** *You betray me?*
>
> **Magneto:** *No. I betrayed them.*

**Why?** Apocalypse would give Magneto what he wanted. Killing all humans.

Comment: I assumed he was talking about his dead family and his living mutant "brothers and sisters".

Comment: Killing all humans probably only was the plot to ultimately free all mutants from control and constraint - the real goal. So having them killed or enslaved by a crazy supermutant god probably isn't a good way to start with.

Comment: "Your thoughts betray you, Father. I feel the good in you."

Comment: So Magneto want to kill Apocalypse because Apocalypse is killing a fellow mutant? Magneto doesn't even know that quicksilver is his son?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Did Magneto find out about Quicksilver?