# What was the reason for Magneto's decision at the end?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

In *X-Men: Apocalypse*, why did Magneto betray Apocalypse? Magneto was very much grieving and angry and seemed very much on board with Apocalypse's plans. All I remember is that Mystique talked to Magneto and the next thing I know Magneto betrays Apocalypse.

Comment: https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/En_Sabah_Nur_(Earth-TRN414)#Apocalypse states "Choking Mystique also led to Magneto and Storm turning on him, so he had to defend himself against both of them too. " but it's a fan-edited wiki.

Comment: Same question here with no answer: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156444/why-did-magneto-betray-apocalypse

Comment: @FuzzyBoots but why would magneto turn on apocalypse because of mystique?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't believe there is a canon explanation for it (although I'll admit that I haven't listened to the Director's Commentary), but as noted, some explanations online tie it to Mystique getting choked out, and [Magneto's lines](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156444/why-did-magneto-betray-apocalypse?noredirect=1&lq=1) suggest this made him realize he was on the wrong side.

> **Apocalypse:** *You betray me?*
>
> **Magneto:** *No. I betrayed them.*

Magneto had allied with Apocalypse with the promise that he would make mutantkind safe by eliminating the human oppressors, but his actions in attacking Mystique, and continuing to choke her even when it's clear that she can't hurt him, makes Magneto realize that he would be trading one oppressor for another.

At the least, that's my interpretation of the scene.

Comment: eh sounds like a good interpretation in lieu of lack of explanation of a really weird or weirdly addressed plot hole. thanks FuzzyBoots